# Amazon RedShift + Rails how do I acces cluster when `Publicly Accessible` set to `No`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-redshift

I use RedShift adapter for my rails application  and everything is great until I try to make cluster non-publicly accessible. In my `database.yml` I use host/port/db/user/password. Do I need any more options to access cluster? Is that possible at all?

Comment: How are you referencing the host? Is it via the DNS name provided as the Endpoint in the Redshift console? This has probably changed from resolving to a Public IP address to resolving to a Private DNS requests, so you need to update the Security Group associated with the Redshift cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the IP of your Rails server to either the VPC security group (if you use a VPC [recommended]) or the Redshift security group (if not using VPC).

If you use a VPC you can place your Rails and Redshift cluster in the same VPC and connections should 'just work'.